# Why do estimates differ so much between Instrumental Variable (ivreg) vs 2SLS (lm)?

Tags: instrumental-variables, treatment-effect, 2sls

I am working with some messy pilot data to figure out whether Instrumental Variable analysis will help interpret the results of a randomized controlled trial I am preparing. Treatment compliance in the pilot study was extremely low (15%) and will probably be low or moderate in the real study. Consequently, the intent-to-treat effect (i.e., just contrasting over group assignment) is likely to be very weak, but I still need to be able to estimate the hypothetical effect of complying with the treatment protocol.

Although the topic of my study is quite different, [this paper on police body cameras](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/303988618_Body-Worn_Cameras_and_Citizen_Interactions_with_Police_Officers_Estimating_Plausible_Effects_Given_Varying_Compliance_Levels) deals with very similar issues (inconsistent compliance among the treatment group, where participants' compliance is probably also confounded with some of the other covariates). I decided to try to adapt their idea, so I started exploring IV analysis as a way to resolve my problem by using randomly assigned group as the instrument of compliance. In R terms:

`ivreg(outcome ~ compliance+covars, ~treatment+covars, myData)`.

However, it's also my understanding that 2-stage least squares approach (2SLS) should provide identical coefficients as IV for the minimal "just identified" model:

`ivreg(outcome~compliance|treatment,myData`

despite s.e. being incorrect. (just for one source, these [course notes](http://www3.grips.ac.jp/~yamanota/Lecture%20Note%208%20to%2010%202SLS%20&%20others.pdf).)

**My problem** is that strictly following these instructions, 2SLS is predicting double the effect of Compliance that ivreg is predicting in the just identified model. That doesn't pass the sniff-test to me.

I'm afraid I'm doing something wrong in this very simple analysis. I'm going to include covariates later, but if this minimal model is producing unexpected behavior, I really don't know how to interpret the more complicated model(s).

**Can anybody suggest what circumstances one would expect estimated coefficients in 2SLS to be MUCH larger than IVreg, and which model I should trust (if any)? or how I should change my approach?**